# Javascript = Building a variable name from strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Let's say I have:

```
var acDeMa = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];  
var test1 = 5;

var test2 = 7;

var test3 = 3;

var piece1;

var piece2;

var piece3;

if ( test1 == 5 )
{piece1 = "ac";}

if ( test1 == 7 )
{piece2 = "De";}

if ( test1 == 3 )
{piece3 = "Ma";}
```

How do I then combine those pieces, recognise it as the Array from earlier, and copy the values from my Array into a new Array?

```
var finishedArray = (piece1 + piece2 + piece3);
```

I want this effect below, basically, but without having to specifically type it's name (acDeMa):

```
var finishedArray = acDeMa;
```

How would I go about doing this? The reason for doing this is because I have about 60 arrays and I'm comparing two at a time. Some of the arrays have things in common, so rather than have 60 separate 'if' statements, I'd rather piece the correct Array name together using a few choice 'if' statements (that cleverly find what various Arrays have in common), and then using that as my Array.

No, I do not want to have the numbers 5, 7, and 3 in a new Array. I want the numbers: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 in finishedArray, but because those numbers could be different every time, I DON'T want to write:

```
var finishedArray = acDeMa;
```

or

```
var finishedArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really recommended but if you are working in the global context you could use the window object like this

```
var finishedArray = window[piece1+piece2+piece3];
```

That will create a reference to your original array. To get a separate copy use the `slice` method

```
var finishedArray = window[piece1+piece2+piece3].slice(0)
```

Comment: Even better would be the `self` object

Comment: Hi, I'm a Noob at programming and I haven't covered classes yet. If I just copy and paste one of those lines in it should work fine? Or does it need extra lines I'm not aware of? Also, why is it not really recommended? Thanks :)

Comment: I tried using your command, but it thought Window was a variable and complained that it hadn't been made yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array, start off with an object:

```
var myArrays = { acDeMa : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] }
```

and then

```
var finishedArray = myArrays[piece1 + piece2 + piece3];
```

Comment: How would I store over 60 Arrays in myArrays?


var myArrays = { acDeMa : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], acDeMo : [1,4,5], acDoMa : [3,6,1], adDuMu : [6,3,9,99] }

?

Comment: Didn't work.

Unity says:

Error: BCE0051 Operator '+' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'Object' and a right hand side of type 'Object'.

It's referring to the piece1 + piece2... etc

Comment: Currently I have:

var lookUpArrays =
{fHighD : [100,300,340,347,400,440,447], 
fHillD : [110,200,240,247,310,382,389,510,582,589]};

var piece1 = "f"
var piece2 = "HighD"

var array1 : Array = new Array();

array1 = [piece1 + piece2];
I have also tried piece1.concat(piece2); but apparently concat is not a member of Object.

Comment: With that, `array1 = lookUpArrays[piece1 + piece2]` should work