# Can't Concat 4 Arrays together

Tags: arrays, null, nullreferenceexception, concatenation

```
var upArray : Array = new Array();
var downArray : Array = new Array();
var leftArray : Array = new Array();
var rightArray : Array = new Array();

upArray = [100,110,120,130,140,150,200,210,220,230];
downArray = [100,110,120,130,140,150,200,210,220,230];
leftArray = [100,110,120,130,140,150,200,210,220,230];
rightArray = [100,110,120,130,140,150,200,210,220,230];

var joinedArray : Array = upArray.Concat(downArray,leftArray,rightArray);
```

**The code above gives me the compiler error:**

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TerrainGenerator2.Main () (at Assets/Scripts/TerrainGenerator2.js:516)

**Using Unity / Javascript / Unityscript.**

**Please help!**

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe upArray.concat(downArray,leftArray,rightArray). Javascript is case sensitive. Word "Concat" should be all small letters.

```
var upArray  = new Array();
var downArray = new Array();
var leftArray = new Array();
var rightArray  = new Array();

upArray = [100,110,120,130,140,150,200,210,220,230];
downArray = [100,110,120,130,140,150,200,210,220,230];
leftArray = [100,110,120,130,140,150,200,210,220,230];
rightArray = [100,110,120,130,140,150,200,210,220,230];

var joinedArray = upArray.concat(downArray,leftArray,rightArray);

alert(joinedArray.length);
```

It's worked in the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gregnozik/2C3UT/

Comment: In Unity, Concat needs a capital C. I've tried without a lower-case, only to have it suggest capital.

Comment: Try to do one by one . var joinedArray = upArray.Concat(downArray,leftArray)

Comment: Tried that, too. Same problem.
I think it's something to do with what the Arrays are classed as. Unity is screwy like that with references and objects.

Comment: When you declare the joinedArray, remove : Array . So you will have only var joinedArray

Comment: I commented some above code, and now it works... I commented out a lot of it though and I'm not sure how it's interfering.

Comment: Yes you are right. Try to declare array as class upArray = new Array(); upArray.push(100,110,120);

Comment: I made some progress. It's actually being caused by this issue over here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537448/javascript-building-a-variable-name-from-strings    
PLEASE HELP!